# Random coordinates and Disabling the move for the next random set

Tags: c++

I just want to know if what I coded is right or if going the right way. Any pointers and help is deeply appreciated.

I need to write a code that can random through a set of coordinates and then when that coordinates has already been chosen from the first set of randoms it will be disabled or the program will have to random a value again.

I already have coded something and I just don't know how I can check it if it's right since i'm dealing with random numbers here.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x;
int y;
void random(), check(), rad();
const int numRows = 10;
const int numCols = 10;
bool moveflag [numRows][numCols];
string move [numRows][numCols] = 
{
       {"A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "I1", "J1"}, //row1
       {"A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "I2", "J2"}, //row2
       {"A3", "B3", "C3", "D3", "E3", "F3", "G3", "H3", "I3", "J3"}, //row3
       {"A4", "B4", "C4", "D4", "E4", "F4", "G4", "H4", "I4", "J4"}, //row4
       {"A5", "B5", "C5", "D5", "E5", "F5", "G5", "H5", "I5", "J5"}, //row5
       {"A6", "B6", "C6", "D6", "E6", "F6", "G6", "H6", "I6", "J6"}, //row6
       {"A7", "B7", "C7", "D7", "E7", "F7", "G7", "H7", "I7", "J7"}, //row7
       {"A8", "B8", "C8", "D8", "E8", "F8", "G8", "H8", "I8", "J8"}, //row8
       {"A9", "B9", "C9", "D9", "E9", "F9", "G9", "H9", "I9", "J9"}, //row9
       {"A10", "B10", "C10", "D10", "E10", "F10", "G10", "H10", "I10", "J10"}
};

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col)
        cout << move[row][col] << "\t";
        }

random();



system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void rad(){
 cout << endl << move[y][x] <<endl;
moveflag[y][x] = true;
}

void random(){
 x = rand() % 10;
y = rand() % 10;
check();
if(!moveflag[y][x])
{rad();}
}

void check(){
 if (moveflag[y][x])
 {random();}
 }
```

Comment: If you want your code reviewed you should post to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 1: Can you use C++11 or higher? 2: Is it any problem having the input data copied?

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, so there's a separate place for that here. I'm sorry. I'm just new to this website.

Comment: @Neijwiert Now that you mention it. I'm actually ignorant of that. I don't even know version of C++ i'm using. All I know is that I use Dev-C++  as my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this sort of approach is that the rejection rate of random numbers will increase steadily as the algorithm progresses.

A better approach is to *shuffle* the input coordinates, and subsequent to that, read the shuffled set in order.

Use `std::random_shuffle` to do that.

Comment: Absolutely. You can even pass in your favourite generator to std::random_shuffle.

Comment: After reading your comment I researched about random_shuffle and I just can't figure out how I would use that for my 2D array. And output the new shuffled coordinates one at a time since all the examples I saw outputs all the shuffled numbers at the same time.